# Samba4 as an Active Directory Controller and bind9 zones

Tags: bind, samba4

I am trying to setup Samba4 as an active directory controller by following these two tutorials:

http://www.matrix44.net/cms/notes/gnulinux/samba-4-ad-domain-with-ubuntu-12-04
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/HOWTO

Before setting up samba4 I had already configured my bind9, creating my zones (forward and reverse) and even further extended bind9 to auto-update from the DHCP server. Following the instructions I realised that my manual zone and the AD DNS Zone added automatically by samba4 where conflicting.

Searching further led me to this discussion https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2012-July/168226.html that ends by the advice that the zones should be removed from bind9 and samba4 should handle all DNS requests.

However my problem is that in my network (which this AD will be used) is a mixture of Windows, Macs and Linux boxes and I'd like to be able to have bind9 manual zones with dhcp updates as well as samba4 dc.

Is there any way to combine the two?

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the advice.

The posting pointed out that the OP had the zone defined twice; once in the static BIND config files and once in the DLZ file generated by Samba.

The correct procedure is to use Samba4 to generate the include file, but it is BIND itself that handles the requests.